# LearnDistribution Vs FindDistribution?

Tags: machine-learning

How would you explain the difference between the new LearnDistribution function and the FindDistribution function? or perhaps the overall ML vs Find framework.

I would think for a sample size of 1000 the following code would produce a consistent histogram. But that isn't the case... why is that?

````
obj = RandomReal[100, 1000];

ld = LearnDistribution@obj
fd = FindDistribution@obj

obj2 = Table[RandomVariate /@ {ld, fd}, 100];
Histogram[obj2[[;; , 1]], PlotRange -> All]
Histogram[obj2[[;; , 2]], PlotRange -> All]```
````

Comment: There are (at least) four issues:  (1) One shouldn't expect very similar histograms even sampling from the same distribution with just a 100 samples - and those two samples are completely independent of each other.  (2) `LearnDistribution` seems to end up with a `SmoothKernelDistribution` which seems to have too small of a default bandwidth resulting in a bumpier distribution, and (3) Because you've chosen a bounded distribution, the default for  `SmoothKernelDistribution` doesn't use the `"Bounded"` option, and (4) `LearnedDistribution` is experimental:  your mileage may vary.

Comment: Also the difference shows up from the `PDF`'s of the estimated distributions.  There's no need to generate histograms:  'Plot[{PDF[ld, x], PDF[fd, x]}, {x, -20, 120}]`.